# AG Grid: cellRenderer disables value formatter

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a custom `cellRenderer` in my AG-Grid and I'm using a `valueformatter`:

```
const columnDefs = R.map(
  R.pipe(x => ({
    headerName: strings[x.name],
    field: x.name,
    valueFormatter: contactInformationFormatter,
    comparator:
      x.name === 'group' || x.name === 'tendency'
        ? selectValueToComparableNumber
        : null,
    cellRenderer: x.compenent !== 'select' ? 'highlightCellRenderer' : null,
    cellEditor: componentToCellEditors[x.component],
    cellEditorParams:
      x.component === 'select' ? cellEditorParams[x.name] : null,
    getQuickFilterText: function(params) {
      return x.component === 'select' ? null : params.value;
    },
  })),
  contactInformationCells
);
```

If I exclude the `cellRenderer`, the formatted values get displayed correctly. If I include it, I get the untransformed values. Is this a bug?

Here is my formatter and my `cellRenderer`:

```
function contactInformationFormatter(params) {
  return strings[params.value] || params.value;
}

import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { getSearchValue } from '../../layout/header/search-value-reducer';

function HighlightCellRenderer({ value, ...props }) {
  const searchValue = useSelector(getSearchValue);
  if (searchValue && value.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)) {
    return <strong>{value}</strong>;
  }
  return <span>{value}</span>;
}

export default HighlightCellRenderer;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a bug. You have to use the `valueFormatted` property in the `params` of `cellRenderer` to get the formatted output of `valueFormatter`. `value` property holds the original unformatted data. So the `cellRenderer` will be like

```
function HighlightCellRenderer({ valueFormatted, ...props }) {
  const searchValue = useSelector(getSearchValue);
  if (searchValue && valueFormatted.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)) {
    return <strong>{valueFormatted}</strong>;
  }
  return <span>{valueFormatted}</span>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was breaking my head to find what was wrong. The ag-grid docs says _"It is possible to use a combination of both, in which case the result of the value formatter will be passed to the cell renderer."_- but they didn't mention that you had to use valueFormatted field.

Comment: In case anyone is reusing the same cell renderer for fields with and without value formatter - 

` value = params.valueFormatted!=null ? params.valueFormatted : params.value; `